# No hash nor version when generating rlib

Tags: rust, rust-crates, rlib

In both [official docs](http://doc.rust-lang.org/tutorial.html#a-minimal-example) and on [rustbyexample.com](http://rustbyexample.com/crates/lib.html) it is stated that when compiling a library (`--crate-type=lib`) the generated library file will have a hash in their filename, like `libworld-<HASH>-0.42.rlib`.

But when trying on my box it doesn't generate any hash (nor version) on filename, it´s just "lib" + library name + ".rlib" (like `libworld.rlib`).

**Is this officially changed?**

By the way, I'm using version 0.12.0-pre-nightly with Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also asked this question on rust's subreddit and [steveklabnik kindly answered](http://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/2f6p84/no_more_hash_when_compiling_a_library/ck6fllq).

It appears so that [yes, this have been changed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/complete/0035-remove-crate-id.md#naming-library-filenames):

> Under this new scheme, the new output filenames by the compiler would
>   be:
>
> ```
> lib<name>.rlib
> ```
>
> Note that both the <version> and the <hash> are missing by default.
>   The <version> was removed because the compiler no longer knows about
>   the version, and the <hash> was removed to make the output filename
>   predictable.

This change seems to be due the depreciation of `rustpkg` in favor of `cargo`.